# Converting XML to document in java creates null document

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to parse xml, downloaded from the web, in java, following examples from here (stackoverflow) and other sources.

First I pack the xml in a string:

```
String xml = getXML(url, logger);
```

If I printout the xml string at this point:

```
System.out.println("XML " + xml);
```

I get a printout of the xml so I'm assuming there is no fault up to this point.
Then I try to create a document that I can evaluate:

```
InputSource is= new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(is);
```

If I print out the document here:

```
System.out.println("Doc: " + doc);
```

I get:
    Doc: [#document: null]

When I later try to evaluate expressions with Xpath I get java.lang.NullPointerException and also when just trying to get the length of the root:

```
System.out.println("Root length " + rootNode.getLength());
```

which leaves me to believe the document (and later the node) is truly null.

When I try to print out the Input Source or the Node I get eg.

Input Source: org.xml.sax.InputSource@29453f44

which I don't know how to interpret.

Can any one see what I've done wrong or suggest a way forward?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocumentBuilder.parse(InputStream) returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018868/documentbuilder-parseinputstream-returns-null)

Answer (score 0):

You may need another way to render the document as a string.

For [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/):

```
 public static String toString(final Document document) {
   try {
     final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);

     final XMLOutputter outp = new XMLOutputter();
      outp.output(document, out);
     final String string = out.toString("UTF-8");
     return string;
   }
   catch (final Exception e) {
     throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot stringify document.", e);
   }
 }
```

The output

```
org.xml.sax.InputSource@29453f44
```

simply is the class name + the hash code of the instance (as defined in the Object class). It indicates that the class of the instance has toString not overridden.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't it's the conversion to string that is problem, when I later try to evaluate expressions with Xpath on the document I get a "Null node" exception but I can try it out if you tell me where XMLOutputter() comes from?

Comment: This applies only if you use JDOM (other libraries may have similar classes): http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html