# Parsing XML from API

Tags: java, api

I'm trying to parse the XML from https://isc.sans.edu/api/infocon, specifically the status node, but I can't even seem to load the XML doc:

```
 URL url = new URL("https://isc.sans.edu/api/infocon");
 URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

 InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();

 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

 Document doc = db.parse(responseStream);

 System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

`doc` is always null, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems like to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2019407/1450348. I ran your application and I can see that the parsing has been done successfully.

[image]